# How can I make the constructor of a class access an overloaded function based on the argument?

Tags: c++, overloading

I have the following scenario: The class `internalEntity` is supposed to store data in many different forms (e.g. `boolCloud`, `std::vector<TRIANGLE>`, etc.). When creating this object the constructor is supposed to call the correct `initEntity()` function based on the arguments. How can this be done without overloading the constructor as well as the functions?

For example when executing

```
internalEntity myEntity(bCloud, "My bool Cloud");
```

where *bCloud* is a `boolCloud` i want the first `initEntity()` function to be called.

This example does not work but the `typename T` part is supposed to illustrate what I want to do.

```
class internalEntity
{
public:
    internalEntity(typename T, std::string name) { initEntity(T, name); };

    void initEntity(boolCloud& bCloud, std::string name);
    void initEntity(std::vector<TRIANGLE>& triMesh, std::string name);
    void initEntity(std::vector<dvec>& pointCloud , std::string name);

    void deleteEntity();

    //...


};
```

Answer (score 0):

A common solution for this situation employs the assistance of a helper class:

```
template<typename T> struct initialize_me;

class internalEntity
{
public:
    internalEntity(typename T, std::string name)
    {
        initialize_me<T>::please(*this, name };

// ... The rest of the class declaration.
```

This forward declaration lets you define the rest of the class, before getting to the business at hand. At that point, this becomes a simple case of specialization:

```
template<> struct initialize_me<bool> {

    inline static void please(internalEntity *me, const std::string &name)
    {
          boolCloud whatever_this_is;

          me->initEntity(whatever_this_is, name);
    }
};
```

And similarly for every other specialization necessary. It's unclear from your question where the first parameter to the overloaded `initEntity`s come from. If they are members of the same class they can be passed here via the `me` pointer, normally. If necessary, to tighten-up the access, the helper class can be a `friend`.

It becomes a bit dicier if initialization must occur in the initialization section of the constructor, and cannot be defered to the body like in this situation. Then, the solution will depend on the exact particulars, and a concrete, specific example, will be needed before figuring out the solution.